# Wordpress Custom Query Pagination. How do i add pagination to this?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am currently getting all the post from the db via a query. The php code included is part of a custom Wordpress template. I am using custom meta boxes from: https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress

what do i need to do to paginate every 6 post?

```
         <?php 
            //get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); 
            echo'<h2 class="section-header-dark">'.get_the_title().'</h2><hr>';

                //adjusting the query
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'blog',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                    'order' => ASC
                );

                // The Query
                $latest_post = new WP_Query( $args );
                // The Loop
                if ( $latest_post->have_posts() ) 
                {
                    while ( $latest_post->have_posts() ) 
                    {   
                        $latest_post->the_post();

                        $desc = wpautop( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_cw_desc', true ) );

                        echo'<div class=""><h5 class="">'. get_the_title(). '</h5>';
                        echo $desc;
                        echo'<h6 class="news_date f_right"><i>'. get_the_date(). '</i></h6>';
                        echo'</div><hr>';

                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    // no posts do nothing
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `'posts_per_page' => 6` and add the `paged` Paramter to the query.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 6,
  'paged' => $paged
);

?>
```

Visit http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination for more details.